# Is this an example of a topological sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph, computer-science

Looking at all of my friendships as well-connected, could a topological sort be used to determine how I know one of my friends? (i.e. see below for example)

Like this:

[image: friendship graph]

So from above, the topological sort could be:

me, friend 1, friend 2, friend 3

me, friend 2, friend 1, friend 3

Is this a valid example of when such a sort could be used, to determine how I may know a friend?  Will there be any cycles if everything takes place from my perspective?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You don't know friend 1 through friend 2, or vice versa.

Comment: [Yes/no questions about an example are not a good fit for this site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions). Answers to such questions are rarely useful to anyone except the original asker. The purpose of this site is to create a useful repository of high quality questions with answers. Instead of asking "is this an example of _X_", ask "what is _X_".

Answer (score 2):

How could you direct the friendship to act like a well-directed graph!

I doubt whether this question is valid as the topological sorts are valid for directed graphs only!

BTW, as the figure suggests you can get to know the number of friends whuch are having indirect connection with you.

As from your picture,`friend3` is an indirect friend of yours. Next, your image doesn't have a directed cycle as the traversal node never reaches back to you after completing traversal of all the nodes.

Also, the topological sorting of your friendship can be any of the following :-

```
you--->friend1--->friend2--->friend3

you--->friend2--->friend1--->friend3
```

I hope this clears your confusion/doubt! Please,PLEASE, this is not at all a valid idea. I'd term it as vague and absurd idea.

Comment: Yeah that is what I mean.  I mean, can I use a topological sort to determine how I may know somebody through another friend?  Is there the possibility of cycles in this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use to know it but you won't get the connections after first connection directly as after the first connection you won't be knowing anyone!